# How do I use the string value from one class in another class?

Tags: java, string

I'm very new to Java and some help would be appreciated! When I compile/run "Driver.java", it will ask the user to type in their name. And what the program's supposed to do is take that name and pass it to the class in "Greeter.java" to print out a final message.

I'm trying to implement a constructor that accepts a string parameter, representing the name of the person my program is greeting. And I have to use this parameter to initialize the private instance variable I declared in my "Greeter" class. This is where I got stuck, but here's what I have so far:

Here's my "Driver.java":

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("What is your name? ");
      String name = scanner.nextLine();
      Greeter greeter = new Greeter(name);
      String greeting = greeter.greet();
      System.out.println(greeting);
   }
}
```

And here's my Greeter.java:

```
public class Greeter
{
   String inputName; (This is where I got stuck)

   public string greet()
   {
      return "Hello " + inputName;
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a constructor

try

```
public class Greeter
{
   String inputName; 

   public Greeter (String inputName) {
     this.inputName = inputName;
   }

   public String greet()
   {
      return "Hello " + inputName;
   }
}
```

Comment: It should be `String` not `string`

Comment: Thanks! Was just about to ask about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make constructor that will take argument that ll be used in your Main class :

```
public Greeter (String inputName) { // constructor with parameter that ll be called when Greeter's instance ll be created.
     this.inputName = inputName;
}
```

when any place `Greeter greeter = new Greeter(`String");`will be called then`inputName` variable ll be initialized.

so whenever you will created instance of class using argument constructor it ll initialize inputName variable.

```
public class Driver
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("What is your name? ");
      String name = scanner.nextLine();
      Greeter greeter = new Greeter(name);
      String greeting = greeter.greet();
      System.out.println(greeting);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Greeter greeter = new Greeter(name);
```

To do this you need a constructor which accept a `String` variable as input argument in `Greeter` class

```
public class Greeter {
 String inputName;

 public Greeter(String inputName) { // matching constructor
    this.inputName = inputName;
 }

 public String greet() {
    return "Hello " + inputName;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GO through the following codes,

```
public class Greeter {

  private String name;

  public Greeter() { }

  public Greeter(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }

  public String greet(){
      return "Hello "+ getName();
  }
```

}

```
public class Driver {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter your name : ");
      Greeter greeter = new Greeter(input.nextLine());
      System.out.println(greeter.greet());

  }
```

}

Good Luck !!!

Answer (score -1):

change you Greeter class.

```
public class Greeter{
   private String inputName;    

   public Greeter(){

   }

   public Greeter (String inputName) {
     this.inputName = inputName;
   }

   public String greet()
   {
      return "Hello " + inputName;
   }

}
```